# Pandas performing a SQL subtraction between two dataframes

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have two dataframes. First there is DF1:

```
ID      Other value
1           a
2           b
3           c
```

and then there is DF2, which is a subset of DF1:

```
ID      Other value
1           a
```

I want to create a third dataframe that would be the equivalent of a minus in SQL: dropping all the observations in the intersection of the two dataframes. This would leave me with DF3:

```
ID      Other value
2           b
3           c
```

I've been trying to use pandasql, but it doesn't seem to like my sql. The code is as follows:
    from pandasql import *
    import pandas as pd

```
pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())
train = pysqldf(""" SELECT * FROM DF1 WHERE ID 
                           NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM DF2) """)
```

I get the error

```
Error on sql  SELECT * FROM DF1 WHERE ID 
                           NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM DF2)
```

Any ideas on what is going wrong or how I might achieve this quickly using some other pandas functionality. I can do the exact same thing in R with no problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it

```
df1[df1.ID.isin(df2.ID) == False]
```

Comment: I think his `ID`s is an index. Also, (at least in .13) you won't need the `tolist()` on df2.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a bunch! I didn't need the tolist().

Answer (score 2):

You can subtract Indexs (which is set minus):

```
In [11]: df1
Out[11]: 
   Other value
ID            
1            a
2            b
3            c

In [12]: df2
Out[12]: 
   Other value
ID            
1            a

In [13]: df1.index - df2.index
Out[13]: Int64Index([2, 3], dtype=int64)

In [14]: df1.loc[df1.index - df2.index]  # assuming IDs are unique
Out[14]: 
   Other value
ID            
2            b
3            c
```

Another option available in 0.13 is to use the isin method:

```
In [21]: df1.isin(df2)
Out[21]: 
   Other value
ID            
1         True
2        False
3        False

In [22]: df1[~df1.isin(df2).all(1)]
Out[22]: 
   Other value
ID            
2            b
3            c
```

Comment: If I had posted my answer that would have been 3 answers in 30 seconds :). I wasted my time looking to see if there was a symmetric_difference implemented on indices (which there isn't).

Comment: I'll open an issue. `df1.index.intersection(df2.index).union(df2.index.intersection(df1.index))` should work for unique.